# What are Python 'model objects'?

Tags: python

This question was asked to me in an interview for a Python developer position.

If anyone can answer this with respect to Python then it would be of great help. Generic definitions are also welcome.

Answer (score 6):

Read on wikipedia on Model-View-Controller architecture. Model classes refer generically to the domain model. Martin Fowler on MVC: "a clear division between domain objects that model our perception of the real world, and presentation objects that are the GUI elements we see on the screen. Domain objects should be completely self contained and work without reference to the presentation, they should also be able to support multiple presentations, possibly simultaneously."

In a limited sense in Django and some other Web frameworks this is now synonymous with objects that map to database tables, but as a generic concept is not limited to.

Comment: Right, because for instance in Qt a model is simply a way to represent a data structure in a common interface. It doesn't imply database, though they have models specifically for a database mapping. I just needs to know how to source data and organize it into a conformed structure.

Answer (score 3):

Usually they are objects which map to database tables (their instances map to rows in the corresponding tables).

Comment: this is the most narrow possible explanation of the web ages. When the concept of MVC was invented it did have nothing to do with databases or web views.